# How to download a file programmatically and show it as a download in Android

Tags: android, file, download

I'm trying to make an app to download files, I can do it, but when I go to de Downloads application in the Android device, the downloaded file isn't there. I've tried to download that file in many places but it isn't showing. How can I "publish" that file as a Download?

Comment: can you post cade here?

Answer (score 0):

You can open your target file url in browser and it will be downloaded to device and it will be shown in downloads